# java.lang.NullPointerException at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.DefaultJpaContext.<init>(DefaultJpaContext.java:53)

Tags: eclipselink

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jpaContext': Bean instantiation via constructor failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.DefaultJpaContext]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: Please add more information like code and the full stacktrace

Comment: Where you able to solve this? I am facing same issue while trying to run spring boot tests.